# Trying to have a login page automatically send to username

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is going to be hard to describe since I don't work in Javascript that often.

Currently I am trying to creating a login page.  Upon opening the page I want the user to be automatically sent to the "Enter your Username" tab, meaning I want the cursor to start blinking on it automatically.
The best example I can think of this is in Gmail where when you open the login page, the "Enter your email" tab starts blinking automatically.
I cant get more technical than this.  Any helpful response would be appreciated.

[image: image of gmail login page]

Comment: are you tried any thing?

Answer (score 1):

Either use the new HTML5 `<input autofocus>` attribute on the field you want focused first or use Javascript to call `.focus()` on the input element.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="xax" autofocus />
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F2FZM6)

If You need to use JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('search').focus()
</script>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HXguMy)

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery.. first provide a id to the text box e.g uname and write script as

```
 $(function(){
$('#uname').focus();

})
```

hope you will include .min file & write the above code between `<script>`